# Importing a Table of Data from an Excel File and displaying it on an Online Form using VBScript and HTML

Tags: html, excel, vbscript

I have currently created an online form using HTML and it has been validated using VBscript. The form contains data such as a users name, phone number, email address etc. VBscript then dumps the data to an excel file, where it is saved. Now, that data has to be again displayed on the HTML form in a tabular fashion. How am I supposed to import data from the Excel file? And once I have imported it, how do I display it? Message boxes are out of the question, and even if I embed the table onto the form, how should it be done? Which is an ideal solution?

Comment: Please paste here your code to help you. Check this to create a good question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes. First question posted on this site. Need to learn :)